# Run AMP C++ kernel thread per row

Tags: c++, c++-amp

How to run AMP C++ kernel with thread per row? I got NxN matrix and want only N threads, not thread per element. But `parallel_for_each(res.extent)` accept only that, What should I pass instead of `res.extent` where res is NxN matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `extent` by yourself with the size of one dimension of the matrix (since both are equal it doesn't matter which you pick).

```
using namespace concurrency;
parallel_for_each(extent<1>(res.extent[0]), function);
```

Then make sure you use `index<1>`.

Comment: Thanks. how could I make it tiled?

Comment: By tiled you mean to divide the matrix into smaller squares? If that's what you want to do, you can define a size and divide the matrix extent with it `extent<2>(res.extent[0] / square_x, res.extent[1] / square_y)` and to get the actual index would be to `index<2> _idx = index<2>(idx[0] * square_x, idx[1] * square_y)`. I don't know if this is what u want.

Comment: `parallel_for_each(extent<2>(res.extent[0] / square_x, res.extent[1] / square_y), [=](index<2> idx) { index<2> _idx = index<2>(idx[0] * square_x, idx[1] * square_y); ... });`

Comment: Well I said `square_x` and `square_y` but since it's a square it should be both `square_side` or sth.

Comment: I want the same as `res.extent.tile<tile_size>()` do, but only for N threads, not NxN

Comment: Oh! I've never used this before but here is some documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/amp/using-tiles?view=vs-2019.

Comment: `parallel_for_each(extent<1>(res.extent[0]).tile<tile_size>(), [=] (tiled_index<tile_size> t_idx) {...});` I guess would be.